# Embarcadero ER Studio - Can't connect to Oracle DB

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to connect to Oracle DB from Embarcadero ER studio (9.6). I have oracle DB client 64-bit and embarcadero 64-bit installed in my local machine. I'm trying to reverse engineer a data model from the database which has all the tables/constraints created. However the problem is embarcadero is not letting me to connect to the oracle db and error message is as below.

Can anyone please suggest what's going wrong here?

**Error message:**

```
Can not load OCI, please verify that oci.dll or ociw32.dll exists in your path. Please make sure your version of OCI is 7.3.4 or greater.
```

Note that I have updated the 'Path' environment variable as per the error message above but it's still not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your oci.dll file located? Try to add also `bin` path of that folder.

Comment: oci.dll file is located in oracle client installation path's bin folder.

"Try to add also bin path of that folder". - in which folder bin path should be added?

Comment: Then add also the parent of bin folder.

Comment: You mean to the 'PATH' environment variable?

Comment: Yes, what else?

Comment: No, this didn't work.